# Ubuntu MATE suspend during boot and shutdown

Tags: boot, 16.04, suspend, shutdown, ubuntu-mate

I recently installed Ubuntu MATE 16.04 onto an Acer Aspire One netbook.
During the install, the netbook went into suspend every 30 seconds. Pressing the power button would wake the netbook up and the install continued successfully after about 80 suspends.
Now my problem is that during boot the netbook will suspend itself every 30 seconds at the login screen. Usually I can log into the netbook with one suspend but sometimes two.
Once logged in, there are no problems.
Then at shutdown ( using Ctrl+Alt+Del and click Shutdown), the netbook suspends again. When I press Power to wake the netbook up from suspend, I am at the login screen. I click the power icon in the upper right corner and select shutdown and then the netbook will shutdown.
After searching, I found a similar question on ubuntu-mate.community but there was no solution. It did mention that `sudo poweroff` from a terminal would avoid the suspend at shutdown. Typing in the password is a slightly less annoying procedure than the suspend.
Is there something I can do to prevent these suspends?

Comment: Please try updating your BIOS to the latest version available on ASUS's Support site -- this may fix the issue. If it does not, this Arch Linux thread has at least one possible workaround: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=178047

Comment: @NickWeinberg Thank you! The workaround worked. I will look into updating the BIOS. Again, thank you.